# PHP secure session library used, but some time session gets destroy.

Tags: php, apache, session, session-cookies

In my project a library is used to secure session, Sometime I observed that my session gets destroyed suddenly.

https://github.com/ezimuel/PHP-Secure-Session/blob/master/SecureSession.php

First I want ton know what is the purpose of this library, we can to these setting from php.ini as well.

KEY_... a new created what is the use of this KEY.

When I use print_r inside open(), I get below sample result

```
Hqx_SecureSession Object
(
    [_debug:Hqx_SecureSession:private] => 
    [_key:protected] => 5ò™6žÝ°rIÐß'k Êii07ÀtCzªt@ü¸"‡ÄCžA¼ÿ£g{IP
    [_path:protected] => c:\hqp\xampp_1.7.4\tmp\
    [_name:protected] => PHPSESSID
    [_ivSize:protected] => 16
    [_keyName:protected] => KEY_PHPSESSID
    [_cookieParams:protected] => Array
        (
            [lifetime] => 7200
            [path] => /
            [domain] => dev.autoquotes.insurance.com
            [secure] => 
            [httponly] => 1
        )

    [_sessionId:protected] => 
    [_logger:Hqx_SecureSession:private] => 
)
htq827r4rjh9ob05nhlqb8vmd5ai52djb0bd0l42vk9un26df541c:\hqp\xampp_1.7.4\tmp
```

Comment: It looks like it's a wrapper to encrypt the session data. Why do you think you need to encrypt your sessions? Furthermore, it's using the [outdated mcrypt libraries](http://blog.remirepo.net/post/2015/07/07/About-libmcrypt-and-php-mcrypt).

Comment: Encrypting session for security purposes. I am running site on PHP5.3. whatis KEY_... name I saw in cookies?

Comment: @Machavity the OP does not say how recent the project is, we only assume this based on the problem.

Comment: You do realize 5.3 is [End of Life](http://php.net/eol.php), right? That's a far bigger security problem for you than sessions. But it still doesn't explain why you want to encrypt your sessions

Comment: It's a bad session wrapper. It does not do locking, so you will lose data when having concurrent requests with the same session id.  It installs itself as the new session handler, and after that, if the mcrypt extension is missing, throws an exception. It uses CBC mode without explicitly do padding. All in all I wouldn't use this class at all. Also note that "just encrypting it" is not the answer to security. Name the threat you fear. What do you want to prevent to happen?

Comment: thanks, what is the purpose of KEY_ name in cookies?